# Firebase returns random values when retrieving object of data to a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, object, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve Data from Firebase into a Listview. Although it does retrieve the data correctly, it displays some random values after my project ID. My database looks like this: [image]
I'm creating an object containing all values within each of those string under "Buyers" and then I want certain values shown in the Listview ("Navn" and "Telefonnr". But as shown, it gives me what appears to be a random generated string (Changes each time I activate the activity). My code looks like this (Buyers class/object shown below):
Update!: Solved, updated code is posted to people who need it :)

```
            private ListView mUserList;

        private ArrayList<String> mUsernames = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_existing_customer);

            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buyers");

            mUserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UserListView);

            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames);

            mUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();
                        Log.v("YourValue,","Map value is:" +map.toString());
                        Log.d("TAG", "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(map);
                        mUsernames.add(buyerList.getData());
                    }
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

This is the "Buyers" class:

```
public class Buyers {
private String car_Value;
private String interest;
private String driverLicenseNr;
private String name;
private String personNr;
private String phone_Number;

public Buyers(Map<String,String> map){
    car_Value = map.get("Bil");
    interest = map.get("Interresse");
    driverLicenseNr = map.get("Kørekortnr");
    name = map.get("Navn");
    personNr = map.get("Personnr");
    phone_Number = map.get("Telefonnr");
}
String getData()
{
    return (name + phone_Number);
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that in your adapter, you are displaying your Buyers object. To get the value you need, either override the ToString() function or add getters for the values needed. Please add your adapter's code to the question.

Comment: This is all there is, you can see everything. The arrayAdapter is just used like that I guess, I'm new at this, just saw some videos, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a list of objects of your class Buyers populated with data from database hence its printing the id of each of that class. Each of those objects has the data though...

solution:

- change mUsernames to an ArrayList
- create a getter inside BuyerList that returns the data you want to display 
  eg : String getData() { return car_value + interest) };
- then add that data to your list
  mUsernames.add(buyerList.getData);

Comment: Well, this does make a lot of sense to be honest, apart from the void in the return, as void can't return :) I try to make it use with "String getData()..." instead, but doesn't seem to work. Do you have an idea to make that part work? And isn't mUsernames already an ArrayList according to the code, or have I missunderstood something?

Comment: Changing the ArrayList to be strings instead of "Buyers" worked! My updated code is in the description, thank you so much!